# Handling GCM Registration Id (Which is expiring after seven days)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing app on GCM already i have registered in GCM. But after seven days the keyID is expiring. After expiring the app is again start from first onwords from registering..

My code for checking registration

```
if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(First.this)) {
                        // Skips registration.

                    Intent regact = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                            LoginScreen.class);
                    startActivity(regact);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Already registered with GCM",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Intent mainact = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainact);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Have to Register with GCM",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

This is condition for checking the GCM for registered or not. After seven days it is getting unregistered please help me i cant find the solution...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

try below code..

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Automatically registers application on startup.
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            // save your id
        }
```

Comment: Hi Dhawal, Thanks for ur reply yar.. actually im checking condition like  GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(SplashScreen.this) in splashscreen and if registered entering to my activity.else again registered so if it is again registered then data already saved would be lost rit? so i need that id to be saved life time.. please help me in this concept.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

`GCMRegistrar` is a deprecated class which you don't have to use anymore. Even if you choose to continue using that class, you don't have to use `isRegisteredOnServer`. That method (as you can see below), would return false after 7 days pass since you sent the registration ID to your server. That doesn't mean the registration ID expired. It's only meant to make sure that if your server somehow loses the registration ID, it will receive it again after 7 days. If your server is reliable enough, you don't need to rely on this artificial expiration.

```
/**
 * Checks whether the device was successfully registered in the server side,
 * as set by {@link #setRegisteredOnServer(Context, boolean)}.
 *
 * <p>To avoid the scenario where the device sends the registration to the
 * server but the server loses it, this flag has an expiration date, which
 * is {@link #DEFAULT_ON_SERVER_LIFESPAN_MS} by default (but can be changed
 * by {@link #setRegisterOnServerLifespan(Context, long)}).
 */
public static boolean isRegisteredOnServer(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    boolean isRegistered = prefs.getBoolean(PROPERTY_ON_SERVER, false);
    Log.v(TAG, "Is registered on server: " + isRegistered);
    if (isRegistered) {
        // checks if the information is not stale
        long expirationTime =
                prefs.getLong(PROPERTY_ON_SERVER_EXPIRATION_TIME, -1);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > expirationTime) {
            Log.v(TAG, "flag expired on: " + new Timestamp(expirationTime));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return isRegistered;
}
```

If you choose to stop using `GCMRegistrar`, as is recommended by Google, you can simply use the GoogleCloudMessaging.register method to register. That's a blocking method, so you shouldn't run it on the main thread. You should store the returned registration ID in your shared preferences, and only register again when a new version of your app is installed. [This demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java) will show you how to do it.

Comment: Hi Eran, Thank u soo much for ur reply...if u dont mine can u help me out in, how to use this GoogleCloudMessaging.register as im new to this concept.. Please help i need this very urgently.. And my application should be installed first time in user device and there will be so many updations later so how can i do this...